# How to fix dictionary value redefinition not changing the value of another list?

Tags: python

I am making a game of nim, where player remove any no. of stones from a single row among-st three rows. The one who pick the last stone, wins. To play the player input a, b, c...l to remove the stones.But in making of code, it becomes unnecessarily long. So i want to shorten my code by 30 lines. Below is the original code which works:

```
# Nim Game

# Game Variables
row1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
row2 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
row3 = ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

x = ['0', '0', '0']
y = ['0', '0', '0', '0']
z = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']


def board(x, y, z):
    print(x[0] + "  " + x[1] + "  " + x[2])
    print(y[0] + "  " + y[1] + "  " + y[2] + "  " + y[3])
    print(z[0] + "  " + z[1] + "  " + z[2] + "  " + z[3] + "  " + z[4])


def valid_move(a, b, c, d):  # Check for validity of moves
    flag = False
    if set(a).issubset(set(b)) or set(a).issubset(set(c)) or set(a).issubset(set(d)):
        flag = True
    return flag


def rules():  # Respond to input from players.
    if valid_move(move, row1, row2, row3) and not any(item in move for item in already_played):
        if 'a' in move:
            x[0] = " "
            already_played.append('a')
        if 'b' in move:
            x[1] = " "
            already_played.append('b')
        if 'c' in move:
            x[2] = " "
            already_played.append('c')
        if 'd' in move:
            y[0] = " "
            already_played.append('d')
        if 'e' in move:
            y[1] = " "
            already_played.append('e')
        if 'f' in move:
            y[2] = " "
            already_played.append('f')
        if 'g' in move:
            y[3] = " "
            already_played.append('g')
        if 'h' in move:
            z[0] = " "
            already_played.append('h')
        if 'i' in move:
            z[1] = " "
            already_played.append('i')
        if 'j' in move:
            z[2] = " "
            already_played.append('j')
        if 'k' in move:
            z[3] = " "
            already_played.append('k')
        if 'l' in move:
            z[4] = " "
            already_played.append('l')
    else:
        print("Invalid move")
    already_played.sort()
    print('Already played: ' + str(already_played))

already_played = []
while x != [' ', ' ', ' '] or y != [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] or z != [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']:
    board(x, y, z)
    move = list(input().lower())
    rules()
print("Game over!")
```

Now I want to shorten the code under rules() function by making a dictionary of [a, b, c...] with values [x[0], x[1], x[2]...]. And now using for loops to iterate over keys and values. But problem occurs when i set the value( which is an item of lists x, y, z) to " " (which make that item disappear in board(x, y, z)), it is not working that way. It is not making the value = " " in board(). Here is the code that i tried which is not working:

```
# Nim Game

# Game Variables
row1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
row2 = ['d', 'e', 'f', 'g']
row3 = ['h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l']

x = ['0', '0', '0']
y = ['0', '0', '0', '0']
z = ['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']


def board(x, y, z):
    print(x[0] + "  " + x[1] + "  " + x[2])
    print(y[0] + "  " + y[1] + "  " + y[2] + "  " + y[3])
    print(z[0] + "  " + z[1] + "  " + z[2] + "  " + z[3] + "  " + z[4])


def valid_move(a, b, c, d):  # Check for validity of moves
    flag = False
    if set(a).issubset(set(b)) or set(a).issubset(set(c)) or set(a).issubset(set(d)):
        flag = True
    return flag


def rules():  # Respond to input from users.
    rulebook = {'a': 'x[0]', 'b': 'x[1]', 'c': 'x[2]', 'd': 'y[0]', 'e': 'y[1]', 'f': 'y[2]', 'g': 'y[3]', 'h': 'z[0]',
                'i': 'z[1]', 'j': 'z[2]', 'k': 'z[3]', 'l': 'z[4]'}
    if valid_move(move, row1, row2, row3) and not any(item in move for item in already_played):
        for key, value in rulebook.items():
            if key in move:
                value = " "
                already_played.append(key)
    else:
        print("Invalid move")
    already_played.sort()
    print('Already played: ' + str(already_played))

already_played = []
while x != [' ', ' ', ' '] or y != [' ', ' ', ' ', ' '] or z != [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']:
    board(x, y, z)
    move = list(input().lower())
    rules()
print("Game Over!")
```

Please see where is the mistake. And suggest the way to fix it.
If there is another way to shorten the code,that will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `rules()` function?

Comment: It respond to the input from players. For ex, if player make move by input 'a' then it will remove first stone from first row.

Comment: Your `rulebook` doesn't work as `'x[0]'` is just a string and not a reference to the object `x[0]`. But there's great potential for simplification of the whole thing.

Comment: Ohh thats the problem. Please if you know another method then its must be welcomed.

Comment: what type of input you are giving is it single character or a string?

Comment: It is a string.

Comment: does the input follows order like `efg` or `abc`. does 'dg` is valid input

Comment: yes, it is like ab and sometimes abc

Comment: what if input is `dg` or `ac` like non consecutive

Comment: yes dg is a valid input

Comment: ac is also good. bac,  gde are also valid moves

Comment: single character like 'a' is also a valid input

Comment: all of these types of input are valid because these are the subsets of row1 or row2 or row3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made small changes to your board. I am changing played move with 'x' so while printing it will show which are completed which or not yet completed.

```
row1 = 'abc'
row2 = 'defg'
row3 = 'hijkl'

rulebook = dict(zip((row1 + row2 + row3), ['0'] * 12))

already_played = []

def board():
    val = list(rulebook.values())
    x = 0
    for row in [row1, row2, row3]:
        print(' '.join(val[x: x + len(row)]))



def valid_move(a, b, c, d):  # Check for validity of moves
    return any(set(a).issubset(row) for row in [b, c, d])

def rules(move):  # Respond to input from users.
    if valid_move(move, row1, row2, row3) and not any(item in move for item in already_played):
        for x in move:
            rulebook[x] = 'x'
            already_played.append(x)
    else:
        print("Invalid move")
    already_played.sort()
    print('Already played: ' + str(already_played))

while ''.join(rulebook.values()) != 'x' * len(rulebook):
    board() 
    rules(input().lower())
print("Game over!")
```

You can't modify the list elements using a string expression like `'x[0]'`. If you change your string to like this `'x[0] = " "'`. and now use `exec()` to execute the string expression. It will updated the value of `x[0]`.

```
def rules():  # Respond to input from users.
    rulebook = {'a': 'x[0]=" "', 'b': 'x[1]=" "', 'c': 'x[2]=" "', 'd': 'y[0]=" "', 
                'e': 'y[1]=" "', 'f': 'y[2]=" "', 'g': 'y[3]=" "', 'h': 'z[0]=" "',
                'i': 'z[1]=" "', 'j': 'z[2]=" "', 'k': 'z[3]=" "', 'l': 'z[4]=" "'}
    if valid_move(move, row1, row2, row3) and not any(item in move for item in already_played):
        for key, value in rulebook.items():
            if key in move:
                exec(value)
                already_played.append(key)
    else:
        print("Invalid move")
    already_played.sort()
    print('Already played: ' + str(already_played))
```

Comment: Your solution is too brilliant komatiraju. It is also 10 lines shorter than that i am expecting. I will use it for making that perfect. But still i want to know the answer of my above question because It is mystery for me. How shorten the length of rules() function the way i am doing. Value is not working the way i am expecting

Comment: Thanks komatiraju, you solved the problem effectively and this is answer that i wanted to see. I am marking your comment as answer to this problem. Also thanks for everyone who works on my problem and shared their valuable ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Code optimazation usually belongs to the `code review` site. Just a few inputs...

Not sure if I got all your intentions but this approach seems to be overly complicated.

1. Just have one object that represents your board, I'd chose a `List[List]` and then instead of mapping a character to each field (what limits you in your field size) let the user input two integers to identify the chosen field.
2. No need to keep track of the played items in another list, just check if the field in your board is still playable.
3. I'd reduce the use of global variables in functions to a minimum, this allows you to e.g. move them to separate files.
4. You do a lot of unesseccary type conversions, why does `move` have to be of type `List`?

Or your `valid_move` could be simplified to

```
def valid_move(a, b, c, d):  # Check for validity of moves
    return (a in b or a in c or a in d)
```

Comment: I made 'move' of type list because i want to compare it with lists row1, row2, and row3. If move is subset of these then it is considered as a valid move otherwise not. If move is remained a string then i cant compare it with these lists.

Comment: I am sorry I don't know how to implement your suggestion in my code. As i am a beginner. I started learning only a month ago. And I am working on this game just after I finished the basics of python from python crash course book. So If you help me with code then it will become easier for me

Comment: Your suggestion is good. But it will not work because of the rules of game. Sometimes input move consists of more than one letter, for ex input = abc, and computer removes all three stones from 1st row

Comment: So in this case move should be a subset of row1 or row2 or row3

Comment: I am troubling only in shortening the length of code in rule() function.

Answer (score 1):

I have done a code with pandas and numpy, take a look at it! I managed to reduce it to 31 lines of code, almost what you wanted.

I have created a class (Board) in which there is a dataframe (board variable) that defines the positions in your board, within the move(self) method it checks if the move is valid by looking for the input value in the dataframe (board), if found, update the value to ' ', else it loops back to the input. A bit tricky to get to the game_over method but i'm sure you can follow the code up.
I hope you enjoy this code!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Nim Game

class Board:
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = pd.DataFrame(np.array([['a',2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]), columns=['one','two','three'])
        print(self.board)
    def show_board(self):
        print(self.board)
    def move(self,move):
        if move[0] != ' ':
            for index,row in self.board.iterrows():
                if move[0] in row.tolist():

                    column = row.tolist().index(move[0])
                    self.board.at[index,list(self.board)[column]] = ' '
                    self.show_board()
                    if not self.game_over():
                        return False
                    return True
        print('not possible move')
        self.show_board()
        return self.game_over()
    def game_over(self):
        a = self.board.to_numpy()
        return not (a[0] == a).all()



board = Board()
not_game_over = True
while not_game_over:
    print('provide an input')
    move = list(input().lower())
    not_game_over = board.move(move)
print("Game Over!")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer T. Novais. It is pleasant to see that how you packed the game in just 31 lines. As your work is too complex for me to understand cause i am a beginner so this answer goes to the  my collection of those project which I want to learn.

Comment: But please can you solve my original problem that how to shorten the code the way which i am doing. Cause I have to add lots of thing in that game.

Comment: Hi @RishabhSemwal , I think you already have pretty good coding skills, it doesn't look like a beginners code at all. Though i must say, in my rumble opinion, that python greatest strenghts are based on the object oriented programming, the more complex your program is, the better you can organize and structure it with classes/methods (functions).I'm a beginner myself and focused my skills in data analysis and work with classes took me to the next level.

Comment: @ T. Novais, Thanks for the praise. If I had written this code in a day then this is considered as too good code for a beginner. Actually my python journey is just about one month. And after learning the basics, I immediately started to work in this game. I made it slowly slowly by figuring out a problem and solving that (by using Google etc) in that particular day. That's how I reached at this code.  I found your code complex because I skipped the "Class" chapter. But now i am realizing my mistake. Your Code inspire me to learn the "Class". Thanks you very much.